# Extending Nashorn ecma engine to add new operators and types

Tags: javascript, nashorn

A previous developer at our company has implemented their own javascript engine  which we would like to replace with Nashorn.

He has implemented a subset of the ECMA standard so in theory it should be a fairly straight forward operation except he has extended the language slightly!

Best explained by a example of the syntax that his language can support.

```
var today = now(); //create a proprietary object that represents time
var tomorrow = today + 1d;  //Add a day. NOTE 1h is NOT a constant
```

As can be seen he has

- added operator overloading to his own Time class.
- Introduced a new 'type' of number that represents a time duration This type can be instantiated with patterns like  1d, 3d4h5s, 1h, 5m, etc. The code knows how to add/subtract these numbers for time!

The equivalent javascript code would be

```
 var today = now(); //create a proprietary object that represents time
 var tomorrow = today.plus( new Duration( '1d'));  //Add a day.
```

I would like to know if Nashorn has any 'hooks' so that we can extend the language with these 'features' or do we need to rewrite all our scripts?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: you can actually use Date()s (kinda) like that if you only had the constants; `H1=1000*60*60;   alert(new Date(+new Date() + H1))`

Comment: H1 is not a constant. It is actually a type of number.

Answer (score 0):

No, nashorn does not have any hooks to extend the language implemented. I guess you need to do preprocessing of the script - say parser and replace such "+" with ".plus" call and so on - before you submit the script to the nashorn engine.